# How to insert value from function to variable javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i want to add the value of my function to the variable.

for example i have something like this

```
<input v-model="search.steering" @input="onChange('steering')"/>
```

that mean i want to insert the `steering` each i input the text.

here the function

```
onChange(typemember) {
  this.search.typemember
}
```

what im doing here is i add the `typemember` value to `this.search` variable.

so the variable in javascript now will be like this `this.search.typemember` the `typemember` value is taken from `@input="onChange('steering')"`

in this example the variable now will be like this `this.search.steering`. is that posible? or is there anothere way to doing this?

btw im using vue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `this.search.steering` dynamically using `typemember` you'd just need to use square brackets:

```js
this.search[typemember]
```

Comment: owh, i never think it ill work, i think `[]` block is for array. hahaha. thanks..